# How do I fix a broken Lisp directory path for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp, installation, path

I installed a new version of emacs (new for me). I didn't want to overwrite the stock copy so I put it in a group-readable directory ~admin/sw. I point my $PATH there and I'm able to pick it up, but when I run ~admin/sw/bin/emacs I get a whole bunch of warnings and errors:

```
Warning: arch-dependent data dir (/usr/local/libexec/emacs/23.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/) does not exist.
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/23.1/site-lisp' does not exist.
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/23.1/lisp' does not exist.
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/23.1/leim' does not exist.
```

When I compiled emacs I did it as: `make install prefix=~admin/sw.` All of those directories do exist but they exist at ~admin/sw/share/...

How can I configure my environment so that emacs looks there for the files? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than

```
make install prefix=~admin/sw
```

try:

```
./configure --prefix=~admin/sw
make
make install
```

This may require an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .emacs file around ( perhaps dating back to a previous install ) that could have the wrong path in it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. My .emacs file doesn't have any paths in it that reference the above paths. The problem is that my new install is looking for the above directories in the wrong place. I need to figure out how to tell emacs to llok in the correct place...

Comment: Well, without understanding my question you've answered it. When I've run into problems with emacs being obtuse about finding things it's usually been a stray .emacs file from an old install or a stray line in a .emacs file throwing a spanner into the works.

Answer (score 0):

Before I did ./configure - -prefix=CUSTOMPATH > make > make install, I also replaced all instances of /usr/local in src/epaths.in to CUSTOMPATH.

configure script used src/epaths.in to generate src/epaths.h which is used in make install.